# Does BCM43438 Wireless chip in Raspberry Pi 3 support ad-hoc networking?

Tags: wireless

I would like to know if BCM43438 supports ad-hoc mode, as I am planning to purchase 3, or more, Pi 3 to setup a network.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it does:

```
pi@rp3:~ $ sudo iwconfig wlan0
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=1496 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
pi@rp3:~ $ sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode ad-hoc 
pi@rp3:~ $ sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid fufutos
pi@rp3:~ $ sudo iwconfig wlan0 channel 11
pi@rp3:~ $ sudo iwconfig wlan0
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"fufutos"  
          Mode:Ad-Hoc  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Cell: Not-Associated   
          Tx-Power=1496 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
pi@rp3:~ $ sudo ifconfig wlan0 10.0.0.3
pi@rp3:~ $ ping 10.0.0.10
PING 10.0.0.10 (10.0.0.10) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.10: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=10.8 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.10: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=24.9 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.10: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=31.1 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.10: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=12.0 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.10: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=12.1 ms
^C
--- 10.0.0.10 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 10.878/18.240/31.129/8.256 ms
```

(.10 is another random machine on my network with the same ad-hoc settings, of course).

/ji