# does the BCM43143 wifi chip on the RP3/RP0 support ad hoc networking?

Tags: networking, wifi

I'm planning on using the virtualhere app to set up a portable usb over ip server as well as giving me a way to screen cast (when i'm away from my home network) to my yogabook, which is irritatingly incapable of ad hoc, and as far as i understand hotspot/AP modes won't work for those kinds of setups.

Also i've seen the chip referred as the BCM43438 but on the [adafruit site](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3400) and a [wiki of compatable wifi's](http://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Wi-Fi_Adapters) it's called the BCM43143. Has this changed at some point?

Comment: There are verifiable photos of the WiFi chip that would strongly suggest it's a BCM43438 on the Pi 3 at least: [this article and accompanying photo from the Pi Foundation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/raspberry-pi-3-specs-benchmarks/), and [this one from raspi.tv](http://raspi.tv/2016/raspberry-pi-3-model-b-launches-today-64-bit-quad-a53-1-2-ghz-bcm2837). There was a ye olde Farnell datasheet that came out at the Pi 3 launch with the wrong number, and it seems to have stuck as a reference.

Comment: ...and [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/raspberry-pi-zero-w-joins-family/) is the reference I was looking for for the Pi Zero W. Definitely the 43438.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question, but you can list list the capabilities of the chip with `sudo iw list | grep -A 12 -i "supported interface modes"`

Comment: actually don't own one yet, this was going to be the deciding factor, but knowing that BCM3143 was a typo helps a lot, as the capabilities of the BCM3438 are answered [here](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/43830/does-bcm43438-wireless-chip-in-raspberry-pi-3-support-ad-hoc-networking) holes in my knowledge lead me to ask the wrong question i guess, but either way thank you, because you did tell me what i needed to know.